# Conjecture $\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\ln^2x+\arccos^2x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\stackrel?=\pi\,\ln\ln2$

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms, closed-form, conjectures

$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln\left(\ln^2x+\arccos^2x\right)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx\stackrel?=\pi\,\ln\ln2$$
Is it possible to prove this?

Comment: Well, Wolfram seems to agree with the result...perhaps some sneaky trick from complex analysis...?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Substitute $x \mapsto \cos x$ to obtain an equivalent formulation:

$$ \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \log(x^{2} + \log^{2}\cos x) \, dx = \pi \log \log 2. $$

You can find my solution [here](http://integralsandseries.prophpbb.com/topic90-90.html?sid=559dea82493ac184c6d95dc1566f7a61#p808).

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Note that $$\ln^2\cos t+t^2=\ln^2\cos t-\ln^2 e^{it}=(\ln e^{it}\cos t)(\ln e^{-it}\cos t)$$
Then let $ e^{2it}=s$ to obtain a contour integral surrounding the simple pole at $s=0$